# Is this video authentic footage from 1952 Washington DC?

Tags: ufo

https://alien-ufo-research.com/ufos-over-dc/

This is one of the research sites claiming its real, its also been included in many documentaries, lates of which The Phenomenon

Without any bias, objectively, never minding what the footage could be showing, is there a legitimate source of it, or can it be proven to be fake?

This is the footage remastered with colour

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Q9UFR6Ph2o

Comment: User was deleted as a sockpuppet, but the question remains valid.

Comment: Please remember the [Code of Conduct](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Comment: Since the [first engineering demonstration of video recording was in November 1951](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Videotape), and the first commercial use was in 1956, any claim of a reasonable quality video recording in the summer of 1952 seems very unlikely.

Comment: Apparently the video was remastered. Even if real footage, one problem is it can be edited to bring out what the editor believes it shows.

Comment: @Charles: I don't think anyone is claiming that. It could have been a film recording from 1952, digitised more recently. (It wasnt, but this makes your argument moot.)

Comment: @WeatherVane: The only people I have seen make the 'remastered with colour' claim (what does that mean in this context?) is the OP. I have seen random commenters on YouTube  also claim it was colourised, but that seems spurious as well.

Answer (score 9):

The Facebook account, [*UFO of Interest*](https://www.facebook.com/1426364457581052/videos/534183647303681/) traced the source of this video, and include a snippet.

> Despite it was explained as a digital animation, this video (here's the full sequence) was often miscaptioned and recycled out of its original context as a real footage. Nope, that was a clip created in CGI for a TV movie broadcast on British television in 2005 titled "UFOs: The Secret Evidence", known in US as "An Alien History of Planet Earth" and broadcast in 2006 on History Channel.

The account goes on to show the video was an attempt to animate the scene from this still shot which shows apparent lights in the sky above the Capitol, which is actually just lens flare from street lights (demonstrated with some geometrical reconstructions), taken in 1965:

> [image: Original image]

A brief examination of the building lighting differences (e.g. the statue at the top is illuminated in the still shot, but not in the video) shows the lens flare photograph and the digital animation were not merely different views of the same event in 1952.